# Getting a specific value from a jquery object passed through an ajax request

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, object, coldfusion

So I currently have a setup where when the user clicks a link, the link's ID is sent via AJAX to a coldfusion page that uses it to make a query and return an object.

The jquery function looks like this:

```
$(".thelink").click(function(){

    var link_id = $(this).attr("id");

    var postData ={
        link_id: link_id,
        }

        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "includes/query.cfm",
            contentType: "application/json",
            data:JSON.stringify(postData),
            datatype: "json",
            success: function(data){
                $("#derpaderp").html(data.DATA.NAME);
            }
        })
})
```

It sends the data over to the CFM file, which does the query, and generates a single row of data. I then use

```
<CFOUTPUT>#SerializeJSON(myQuery, true)#</CFOUTPUT>
```

to return the data. This all works fine, and I can see this in developer tools:

[image: JSON return object]

Now, if you look back at the AJAX function, under "success", I'm trying to basically access the values within the DATA object, and as you can see in the image, I'm getting an error "data.DATA" is undefined.

Any ideas how I can get the values of the items in the DATA object (name, visible_url, landing_url, etc...)

Thank you!

---

**Vlad's answer solved the problem above, but a follow up question:**

If I need to make another query to the CFM file like this:

```
<CFOUTPUT>
    <cfset object0 = RemoveChars(#SerializeJSON(query1, true)#, 1, 2) >
    <cfset object1 = RemoveChars(#SerializeJSON(query2, true)#, 1, 2) >

    #object0#
    #object1#
</CFOUTPUT>
```

It gives me a JSON response like this

[image: Response with multiple queries]

I still need to get info from the DATA objects, however now there are two of them, as seen in the photo above

I'm trying this

```
$.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "includes/query.cfm",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data:JSON.stringify(postData),
        datatype: "json",
        success: function(data){
            var pdata = $.parseJSON(data[0]);
            console.log(pdata);
        }
    })
```

Based on Vlad's answer for the original question, but it's throwing an error.

Comment: What gets output if you put `console.log(data)` in your success function instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your success function you can add [parseJson](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) function. You can use console.log to check the other values you want.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "post",
  url: "includes/query.cfm",
  contentType: "application/json",
  data:JSON.stringify(postData),
  datatype: "json",
  success: function(data){
    var pdata = $.parseJSON(data);
    console.log(pdata.DATA.VISIBLE_URL)

    //$("#derpaderp").html(pdata.DATA.VISIBLE_URL);
  }
})
```

Comment: This works! I could've sworn I tried that too :P Thanks Vlad!

Comment: I edited the original question with a follow up! I tried adding another query to the response, but it seems to be breaking the code

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured out the solution for my follow up question.

Essentially what was happening was I was sending two separate objects back through the AJAX function. Like this:

```
{"COLUMNS": x, "ROWCOUNT":Y, "DATA:Z}
{"COLUMNS": x, "ROWCOUNT":Y, "DATA:Z}
```

This caused a parsing error, as there are 2 objects. I solved this by creating a single object to send back.

```
<cfset object0 = RemoveChars(#SerializeJSON(query1, true)#, 1, 2) >
<cfset object1 = RemoveChars(#SerializeJSON(query2, true)#, 1, 2) >

<CFOUTPUT>
    {"FIRST":[#object0#], "SECOND":[#object1#]}
</CFOUTPUT>
```

And then getting that info in Jquery by doing this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "includes/query.cfm",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data:JSON.stringify(postData),
    datatype: "json",
    success: function(data){
        var pdata = $.parseJSON(data);
        var object1_data = pdata.FIRST[0];
        var object2_data = pdata.SECOND[0];

        console.log(object1_data.DATA.VISIBLE_URL)

    }
})
```

This successfully logs the value of "VISIBLE_URL" from the first query.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Glad you figured it out. I was gonna suggest maybe you can use inner join in your query so you only have one query and you will only return 1 set of json.